# Не работает innerHTML

Tags: javascript

Почему не работает данный код?

```
var headingElement=document.getElementById("main-header");
var text=headingElement.innerHTML;
console.log(text);
```

Chrome выдаёт ошибку

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null
    at file:///E:/Frontend/learn%20JS/2%20part(dom)/script.js:2:25
(anonymous) @ script.js:2

Решение: скрипт надо выполнять после тегов html

Comment: id точно без ошибок написан?

Comment: Точно. Скрипт работает только в самом html файле

Comment: на момент выполнения кода, в разметке нет элемента с указанным id

Comment: Спасибо. Понял свою ошибку